# Pass in a stylesheet as a prop for a render in a functional component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx, next.js

I'm using Next.js, React, Styled JSX, and Postcss if that matters. I need to style an imported component for a specific page. Since the stylesheets are created for a specific component at the time of render, I figured I could just put the custom styles for the component in with the page specific resources and pass them in. But I'm getting the following error:

```
Expected a template literal or String literal as the child of the JSX Style tag (eg: <style jsx>{`some css`}</style>), but got MemberExpression
```

I have two functional renders in two separate directories and files, one a page and the other a component:

```
src/pages/mypage/
    index.js
    styles.css
    myComponentStyles.css
src/components/MyComponent
    index.js
    styles.css
```

Keeping in mind that file/directory referencing is not mirrored from my environment because it's not the problem, here's my code:

**src/pages/mypage/index.js**

```
import MyComponent from '../../components/MyComponent'
import styles from './styles.css'
import MyComponentStyles from './myComponentSyles'

const MyPage = () => {
  return (
    <div className="my-page-container">
      <style jsx>{styles}</style>
      <MyComponent styles={MyComponentStyles} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default MyPage
```

**src/components/MyComponent/index.js**

```
import styles from './styles.css'

const myComponent = props => {
  return (
    <>
      <style jsx>{styles}</style>
      <style jsx>{props.styles}</style>
      <div className="my-component-main-container">MyComponent</div>
    </>
  )
}

export default MyComponent
```

How would I allow `MyComponent` to receive a stylesheet generated by another component?

Comment: Have you tried: <style jsx>{`@import "./styles.css";`}</style>

Comment: @SteveHolgado If you're referring to `MyComponent` the normal style import works. I edited my question for clarity if that's the case. Though, if you're saying to import the style from `scr/pages/mypage/myComponentStyles.css` into the `MyComponent` function directly, that won't work. That would not enable the component to load styles that are passed into it.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not a direct solution to the problem, Styled JSX has a  `:global()` pseudo selector that accomplishes the end goal of styling a component that is outside the scope of the current component. A working example for the given code is:

**src/pages/mypage/styles.css**

```
.my-page-container :global(.my-component-main-container){
  color: white;
}
```

Here is what the Next.js [documentation](https://github.com/zeit/styled-jsx#one-off-global-selectors) says for the `:global()` pseudo selector:

> ### One-off global selectors
>
> Sometimes it's useful to skip selectors scoping. In order to get a
>   one-off global selector we support :global(), inspired by css-modules.
>
> This is very useful in order to, for example, generate a global class
>   that you can pass to 3rd-party components. For example, to style
>   react-select which supports passing a custom class via
>   optionClassName:
>
> ```
> import Select from 'react-select'
>
> export default () => (
>   <div>
>     <Select optionClassName="react-select" />
>     <style jsx>{`
>       /* "div" will be prefixed, but ".react-select" won't */
>
>       div :global(.react-select) {
>         color: red
>       }
>     `}</style>
>   </div> )
> ```